# Converting large series from datetime64[ns] to ISO format with timezone (store as object type)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large series in Pandas to convert many of its timestamp columns into ISO format with timezone(+2:00).

For example:

```
1                          NaT
2                          NaT
3          2019-06-20 11:35:11
4          2020-09-30 12:57:26
                   ...        
9999999    2021-07-17 20:58:01
Name: timestampvalues, Length: 9999999, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Required result as:

```
1                          None
2                          None
3          2019-06-20T11:35:11.000000+02:00
4          2020-09-30T12:57:26.000000+02:00
                   ...        
9999999    2021-07-17T20:58:01.000000+02:00
Name: timestampvalues, Length: 9999999, dtype: object
```

I have tried it with
`df['timestampvalues']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M%:%S.%f')`

But it does not give the desired output.

Comment: That's not a time zone, it's a time zone *offset*.  Make sure you understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.Timestamp.isoformat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.isoformat.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['2019-06-20 11:35:11','2020-09-30 12:57:26'], columns=['timestampvalues'])
df['timestampvalues'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestampvalues'])

df['timestampvalues'] = df['timestampvalues'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp.isoformat(x.tz_localize('CET')))
```

|  | timestampvalues |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2019-06-20T11:35:11+02:00 |
| 1 | 2020-09-30T12:57:26+02:00 |